# Where can I get hold of a 3.2 version of NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.dll?

Tags: nhibernate

Upgrading to NHibernate 3.2, but can't seem to find a 3.2 version of NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider.

Both SourceForge and NuGet claim to have 3.2, but when I download it I get version 3.1.0.4000, which doesn't seem to work with NH3.2 (NHibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate CacheProvider: NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2).

Comment: If something "doesn't seem to work", please always post your expectations and what actually happens, otherwise nobody can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the [NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2) NuGet package, and I'm pretty sure it works with NHibernate 3.2.

It doesn't even exist for any versions other than 3.2, which makes it difficult to believe you are getting and older version.

If you remove all NH-related packages from your project and run the following:

```
PM> Install-Package NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2
```

You should get everything you need.

Now, if you installed via the FluentNHibernate package (which doesn't mark the version referencing NH3.2 as the current one), that's a different problem.

Comment: Care to help me setting it up ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978923/how-to-configure-nhibernates-second-level-cache-in-nhibernate-3-2

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the answer is that NHibernate.Caches version 3.2 has version number set to 3.1.0.4000 for the dll, and that this actually works fine with NHibernate. I had neglected to update one of my references.

Thank you all for your assistance, I will leave this here for reference for others (I did notice a few others having similar problems on other forums).